# How can I manage user data without the login feature?

Tags: .net, mobile

I am making a .net Maui QR code business card application and the application will not have authorization features such as member login and registration.
And my app needs to be able to create business cards for my user, store those business cards, and save new business cards.
How can I provide this feature? Is it possible?

EDIT: This will be a simple internship project and there is currently no one who can technically answer my question. I guess they want me to find a solution and I'm trying to find one.

Comment: Of course that's possible

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But how can I keep track of which user created which cards? Is it from the device features? Or should I keep all data in local storage? (I don't think this is a good idea)

Comment: We can't answer requirements questions for you. Talk to your stakeholders.

Comment: Maui is used for desktop and mobile apps, not for web apps. Local storage would be the norm, e.g. in a JSON file or in SQLite. It would be unusual for such local-first apps to feature an account or log-in system. If a user installs the app on their device, they're the only user.

Comment: You do not need to keep track of anything. Just require the user to reenter their info each time they order a batch of business cards.

Comment: What is hindering you from saving a business card description into a file, and let the user simply choose a file path for this? Like any word processor, text editor or image drawing application does? Then the user can choose if they want the data to be saved locally, or in some network folder, or some cloud-synched folder? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the application will not have authorization features such as member login and registration.

Which is fine when there is no resource to protect.

A QR code business card is basically a card with a web link. Your job is to let them type in the web link and have it spit out a QR code graphic that can be printed on a business card. So there is no resource to protect.

This can be done as an app or web page. Here’s an [example](https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/).

Creating a web page at whatever URL they type in is not your job. Don’t kill yourself trying to add that.

As a hint, this is a long ago solved problem. Look for existing libraries with acceptable licenses to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. But I still don't understand where I can get the 'saved' and 'mycards' data from. The first thing that came to my mind was to convert the 'cardId' string that I assigned to each card into a QR code graphic and share it among users in the application. But as far as I understand, you are saying to convert the entered contact information into QR code.
[To better express what's on my mind](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1313221986012466858)

Comment: Why is there a cardID string?  Give it a file name. The QR is just a URL. Put the info in local storage. What you’re creating is a specialized document editor.

Comment: Also, don’t worry about storing and retrieving unless you were told that’s a required feature. Trying to add stuff you don’t really need is a good way to miss deadlines.

Comment: Actually, it was the project requirements that confused me from the very beginning (net core web api, .net maui, mysql - and when I asked, they said there was no need to log in/signup) so I started to think about this, how will I use these features without logging in? Am I missing something?

Comment: But for now, I will continue the project with API and jwt token, and if I need to store it locally in the future, I will keep the data I need in a file as you suggested.

Comment: "net core web api, .net maui, mysql" are not requirements. That's a tech stack. Requirements are about what you need it to do. Not how it gets done.

Comment: I suggest you start with the simplest thing that could possibly work. Turn a URL string into a QR code. The only hiccup with that is it will force you to choose a language. My advice is pick one you and the team are comfortable with. Everything else can be added later.

Comment: Your first demo could be as simple as a command line app that lets them type: `qr example.gif https://example.com` Then open the example.gif in some image viewer. Do that in a language compatible with whatever tech stack they have in mind (sounds like c# would do) and you'll be well on your way.